# optimize performance of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to dynamically calculate the height of cell of a UICollectionView. I am using this function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

The problem is that it returns the size of every cell before it is displayed. If there are 120 items in the array it will calculate 120 cell sizes before the

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

is called. This is creating big performance problems. It takes up 10 seconds to load the entire collection. If I dont use sizeforitematindexpath, the collection loads in 1 second. How can I solve this problem ?

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 & Swift 3.0

Here is my exact code for the first delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let json = JSON(mySources[indexPath.row])
        var url = NSURL(string: json["cover"]["source"].stringValue)

        var data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL)
        var photo = UIImage(data: data as! Data)

        var height1 = photo?.size.height


        var boundingRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 372, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (photo?.size)!, insideRect: boundingRect)

        let imageHeight = rect.height

        let font = UIFont(name: "Raleway-SemiBold", size: 17)
        let titleHeight = heightForLabel(text: json["name"].stringValue, font: font!, width: 160)
        let restaurantHeight = heightForLabel(text: json["place"]["name"].stringValue, font: font!, width: 160)
        print(restaurantHeight + titleHeight + imageHeight)
        return CGSize(width: 372, height:imageHeight + titleHeight + restaurantHeight + 100)


   }
```

Comment: The first delegate method return size of visible cells not entire items. Can you add little more how you calculate size?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have updated the post to include exact code. The method is returning size for every cell

Comment: fetching data from this method is very bad idea. You should fetch and calculate size out of this method and reload collection view.

Comment: or you can use auto layout instead of calculate each cell's size.

Comment: I am only calculating size out of this method. My data is fetched in another method. mySources array already has the json in it. I am using swifyjson to parse the objects

Comment: You are fetching image data. `var data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL)`. remove that line and check it is still slow.

Comment: How can I use autolayout for calculating height of the cell ?.  My images and other data are variable in size.

Comment: If i remove data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL) how will i compute the image size ?

Comment: use estimateSize, fetch image asynchronously, reload the cell once image is loaded.

Comment: I think fetching image asynchronously is a good idea. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` always computes the size of all your cells at once before starting preparing the cells themselves.

However if I remember well you can prevent that by setting a non-zero value to its `estimatedItemSize` property (the documentation is not crystal clear about it):

> The estimated size of cells in the collection view.
>
> Providing an estimated cell size can improve the performance of the collection view when the cells adjust their size dynamically. Specifying an estimate value lets the collection view defer some of the calculations needed to determine the actual size of its content. Specifically, cells that are not onscreen are assumed to be the estimated height.
>
> The default value of this property is CGSizeZero. Setting it to any other value causes the collection view to query each cell for its actual size using the cell’s preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:) method. If all of your cells are the same height, use the itemSize property, instead of this property, to specify the cell size instead.

So calling the next piece of code might resolve your performance issues:

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 375.0, height: 44.0)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now 2017-08-10 15:22:55.024 rivoto[2090:29518] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger. The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2017-08-10 15:22:55.024 rivoto[2090:29518] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2017-08-10 15:22:55.025 rivoto[2090:29518] Please check the values returned by the delegate.

Comment: This just mean that the size returned by the delegate is too big. If you have some content inset, make sure you are taking them into account.

Comment: even after adding the code. It still calculates height for every item before the cells are loaded

Comment: This doesn't work. Even after setting the estimatedItemSize, it still calls the sizeForItemAt for every item.

Answer (score -2):

You should use reusable cells so that your collection view doesn't load all data at once but only what's on the screen. Which is much less than the total. This will save performance, memory, and will lessen the CPU usage (smoother graphics, less battery consumption).

How to:

for your collectionView:

```
menuCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
```

in the function cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

         return cell
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out. How can I use reusable cells in sizeforitem at index path.

Comment: Thanks. I am already using dequeueReusableCell in cellForItemAt indexpath, but sizeforitemat index path is returning size for every cell

Comment: so if you comment out the size for item thing, will your collectionview be fast (even if UI is worng)?

Comment: Yes if I comment out the size for itemthing, the collectionview is very fast

Comment: you're parsing the json an fetching the nsdata, then converting it to image all inside this method? why not looping over your json in the didload and making an array with all the cell sizes, then feeding this array for this function?

Comment: doing that will let your app cpmpute the sizes once. with your implementation it will redo it everytime you scroll

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion and let u know how it goes. Meanwhile please help me to compute the size only on visible items if possible